# Is it possible that one run element contains several text elements

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am newest in office programming.
I can't found any documents that describes how many text elements may places inside run.
For example, I generated this xml and put it to "document.xml" directly:

```
<w:r><w:t>Text1<w:t><w:t>Text2<w:t></w:r>
```

Document opens without error. But after document saved in the MS Word, this xml is replaced to the:

```
<w:r><w:t>Text1Text2<w:t></w:r>
```

My question: Is user has any way to generate several <w:t> elements inside one <w:r> , without directly changing "document.xml". I need to know this to understand, should I support "several <w:t> inside one <w:r>" situation in the my algorithm that replaces some text in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But don't forget to terminte your tags correctly.

**`<w:t>my text</w:t>`**